# Set title on QGIS map from variable in csv data layer

Tags: qgis, csv, title

How can I set the **title** of a QGIS map based on a name I pass in a .csv file?

I create a separate file 'tombstone_data.csv' that contains two fields like this:

```
source,update_rate
FlightRadar24,1 x per 3 sec
```

however I cannot find out how to use the source field (= 'FlightRadar24') as the title of the map.

Comment: have you imported the CSV as a table in the map, or are you trying to read it from file?

Comment: imported the CSV as a table. Could as well read it from a file if that is easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression for the Label item text.

[image]

Then use:

```sql
attribute(get_feature_by_id('myCsvLayer', 1), 'source')
```

It finds the attribute value from the feature with `id=1` in the `source` field of the layer called `myCsvLayer`.

You will see that once you click <kbd>OK</kbd> the label text is wrapped in `[% %]`. This is so it evaluates as an expression.

```
[%attribute(get_feature_by_id('myCsvLayer', 1), 'source')%]
```

[image]

If you want to identify a feature using an attribute value (like a unique code that exists in your attribute table) use `get_feature` rather than `get_feature_by_id`:

```
attribute(get_feature('myCsvLayer', 'fieldName', 'fieldValue'), 'source')
```

#### Note:

I noticed when I was testing that if you add a CSV via `Layer > Add Layer > Add Delimited Text Layer` the feature `id` starts at 2 which I think must be a bug.

A CSV layer added by dragging it directly into the map canvas starts at 1.